# turn on/off bluetooth in window phone 7.1 (mango)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

The Mango Windows Phone 7.1 Developer Tools have been released. I understand that the API was updated in the beta tool developer.

Can I now use Bluetooth in Windows Phone 7.1?

Answer (score 3):

The are no APIs for interacting with bluetooth, in any way, for third party apps. This is true currently and does not change in Mango.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and can find out from the [updated documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) there is no API for accessing Bluetooth. It would seem to be possible to iterate over the available network interfaces, but I haven't found anything that enables you to communicate explicitly via Bluetooth.